# Exibir Mapa com ponto ionic 2

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic2

Pessoal uso ionic 2 beta em um projeto com ts, tem as cordenadas de um ponto, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para colocar o mapa com a posição atual do usuário e um marcador nas coordenadas salvas.
Como posso fazer ?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Para capturar a posição atual do usuário você pode usar um plugin chamado [Geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/). Para colocar vários marcadores (partindo do pressuposto que tem essas posições em um array) pode colocá-los percorrendo o array e inserindo no mapa a cada interação do array:

```
let markers = arrayDePosicoes.forEach(item => {

   //cria um objeto latLng a partir de coordenadas da posição atual do array
   let currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude,item.longitude);

   //cria o marcador passando a coordenada e o elemento que contém o mapa
   let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: currentPostition,         
     map: map,
     title: 'Hello World!'
   });

});
```

Comment: Eu tenho ja a lat e long, preciso só colocar no map ... sabe como ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que sua dúvida seja bem simples de solucionar. Crie um objeto com as coordenadas e passe esse objeto para o options e depois passe o options na hora de instanciar o mapa na tela. Este código funciona para mim. Espero ter ajudado!

```
    let myPosition = { lat: -19.911911, lng: -43.917486}

    let options = {
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: myPosition
    };
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
```

Comment: capturar a posicao não é meu problema, mas sim exibir o mapa